# Uninstall BlackBerry app installed via Eclipse

Tags: blackberry, uninstallation, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I imported the PaneManagerDemo sample project in my BB Eclipse workspace, and right-clicked on the project > Load Project(s) on Device. I get a Pane Manager Demo icon on my home screen - OK. It doesn't run, because I'm using a Curve 8330 (OS 4.5.0.138), and some of the classes used in the demo are not supported. How do I delete it from my handheld?

When I run:

```
javaloader dir
```

I see:

```
PaneManagerDemo                                0.9              12232     Fri Apr 29 02:57:24 2011
```

The following commands:

```
javaloader info PaneManagerDemo
javaloader info PaneManagerDemo.cod
javaloader info PaneManagerDemo.jar
javaloader info PaneManagerDemo.jad
```

All produce the same output:

```
Name                                           Version          Size      Created
---------------------------------------------  ---------------  --------  ------------------------
PaneManagerDemo.jar                            unable to open file
---------------------------------------------  ---------------  --------  ------------------------
```

The Pane Manager Demo app does not appear in my list of installed applications under Options > Advanced Options > Applications.

What can I do to get rid of the install of this demo and the associated home screen shortcut?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using javaloader *erase* option e.g.

```
javaloader -usb erase -f  [moduleName]
```

where *[moduleName]* is the name of the module (no extension) you want to delete from the list of installed Modules located at: 
Options > Advanced Options > Applications > 'Modules' menu item
or
Options > Device > Application Management > 'Modules' menu item

Answer (score 1):

Run "clean.bat" from the root simulator's installation directory. It will have effect of reinstalling the simulator from zero.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am using an actual Blackberry, not a simulator (my experience with the simulator has been that it's very unstable, and I haven't yet figured out how to simulate my particular handset version). I don't want all of my other apps wiped.

Comment: @RMorrisey: Oh, sorry I have not noticed you are on a real device. Have you tried to go Options > Advanced Options > Applications AND select 'Modules' menu item? It will show the list of installed modules. You can select one and invoke 'Delete' menu item for the selected module. If that does not work, then I think the only thing is to pull out the battery from the device to reset it.

Comment: Aha! There is a listing for it in the Modules screen; however, unlike every other Module listing, I do not get a Delete menu option when I hit Menu on the PaneManagerDemo module. I tried doing a battery pull, but to no avail. (Also, when my BB started up after the battery pull, I got an error dialog with a NullPointerException on the home screen.)

Comment: I've temporarily gotten around the issue; the new modules disappeared when I upgraded to a new release of the Blackberry OS (4.5.whatever the later one is). I'll revisit this and put up an answer if it happens again and I figure out a solution.

Comment: Is it possible that user may to be delete the application after installation.
If yes then how i can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Arhimed's answer is great and will work.  This can also be accomplished from within Eclipse: In Debug Configurations, select your simulator debug configuration, then go to the Memory tab and select "Reset the file system on startup" and "Reset NVRAM on startup."  Then, next time you debug, the device will be wiped before re-installing your app(s) and debugging.

If you don't want to clean the device every single time you debug, make sure to go back into your Debug Configurations and clear those two checkboxes once you are happy with the state of the simulator.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I guess he and I were both on the same wavelength, but not on yours.  When you have the icon for the app highlighted, can you press the Menu button to get a context menu?  You should have a Delete option in that menu.

Comment: No worries. =) There is no Delete option in the menu for icons on the home screen, though.