# black berry emulater no longer works

Tags: blackberry, emulation

My black berry emulater no longer works. When every I run a program from eclipse, it comes up saying 
JVM error 538
FS mltiplr errors
Scroll for availbe commands
Reset

When I click reset it does nothing, frezzes or exits.  It does this no matter program I run

Comment: Have you tried resetting your simulator?  For example, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833163/uninstall-blackberry-app-installed-via-eclipse/5834340#5834340

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning simulator? It is under BlackBerry menu in Eclipse. You can also try to delete .dmp files of your simulator manually.